# Pig UDF loading issue

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I am not able to use the 2 UDF's together

```
REGISTER 'pig.jar';
REGISTER 'piggybankjar';
DEFINE UnixToISO org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.UnixToISO();
DEFINE ToDate org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate();
```

This is the error that I am getting :
Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.UnixToISO as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

When I do not register the pig.jar, this error goes away, but then it fails to load the ToDate UDF?

Am I missing something basic here? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo or not, but you put `piggybankjar` instead of `piggybank.jar`, can you confirm it's just a typo?

Comment: Do you need to register the pig.jar - surely this is built in?

Comment: @CharlesMenguy It is just a typo when I posted the question....not present in the actual pig script

Comment: @ChrisWhite I removed the register code for the pig.jar, then it is not loading the ToDate function. This is the exact error that I get "Could not resolve org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]"

Comment: There were 2 problems. Our inherent pig.jar is of an older version and that did not contain the ToDate UDF. So had to include a new pig.jar. The second issue which was not clear in my question was that, I was reading the times as chararray and so the UnixToISO was throwing an error. Typecasting it to lang fixed it. The error produced was not clear though

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered a similar error while working with Pig.Till now, in all the cases that I have encountered, this error message is misleading. I had the same error for in-built SUM function. After thorough analysis, I realised I was passing the wrong input to the SUM function and the problem was with GROUPing. So I would suggest that you verify your pig-script again ; chances are there is something else wrong most probably some wrong relation being supplied down the flow.